# How can I share a Document Library sub folder only to a target audience?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a document structure where I would like to grant read-only permission to specific group on a sub folder within a document library.

I am using SharePoint 2007

For example:

```
Folder : Business  <--- Document Library  under business I have two sub folder. 

        --->  2009 --> Sub Folder  --> store all docs
        -----> 2010 --> Sub Folder  --> store all docs
```

Now, I have two groups: Group A, Group B. I would like to grant read-only permission for the 2009 folder to Group A and grant read-only permission for the 2010 folder to Group B. I want to make sure Group A people cannot access the documents under the 2010 folder and vice versa.

I have tried to setup a target audience on Business folder. But I am unable to find a way to setup permissions on the sub folder level. Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

This is just configuration:

1. In the document library, hover the mouse over the folder to see the drop down menu.
2. Activate the drop down menu by pressing the down arrow
3. Choose Manage Permissions
4. Click the Actions menu and choose Edit permissions. Confirm that you want to break inheritance of permissions from the parent.
5. Edit the permissions as required.

Obviously, you need to be logged in as someone who can change permissions (a site owner or similar) to be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a way of progamatically doing this you can modify this script to suite your needs: [powershell-to-get-a-list-of-all-folders-in-downloads-pivots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548983/user-powershell-to-get-a-list-of-all-folders-in-downloads-pivots)

I suggest creating groups for each folder you want to set permissions and then put the people in there.  If manual is all you need, then Chris' soulution is perfect :)